# swift getting an array from something like array[0..<10]

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

I want to get a range of objects from an array.  Something like this:

```
var array = [1,3,9,6,3,4,7,4,9]
var newArray = array[1...3] //[3,9,6]
```

The above would access elements from index 1 to 3.

Also this:

```
newArray = array[1,5,3] // [3,4,6] would be cool
```

This would retrieve elements from index 1, 5 and 3 respectively.

Comment: So, what is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

That last example can be achieved using `PermutationGenerator`:

```
let array = [1,3,9,6,3,4,7,4,9]
let perms = PermutationGenerator(elements: array, indices: [1,5,3])
// perms is now a sequence of the values in array at indices 1, 5 and 3:
for x in perms {
    // iterate over x = 3, 4 and 6
}
```

If you really need an array (just the sequence may be enough for your purposes) you can pass it into `Array`'s init method that takes a sequence:

```
let newArray = Array(perms)
// newArray is now [3, 4, 6]
```

For your first example - with arrays, that will work as-is.  But it looks from your comments like you're trying it with strings as well.  Strings in Swift are not random-access (for reasons relating to unicode).  So you can't use integers, they have an String-specific bidirectional index type:

```
let s = "Hello, I must be going"
if let i = find(s, "I") {
    // prints "I must be going"
    println(s[i..<s.endIndex])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
var n = 4
var newArray = array[0..<n]
```

In any case in 
[Slicing Arrays in Swift](http://vperi.com/2014/06/04/slicing-arrays-in-swift/)  you'll find a very nice sample of the Python slice using a extension to Arrays in Swift.

Comment: 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with a range of Int
str[1..<n] is the error when you do that

Comment: @CodyCrank when you say `str`, are you trying it on a `String`?  Swift's strings aren't indexed numerically.

Comment: Yea I thought for some reason apple did something like "str[2]" at wwdc but that was a lond time ago lol